# Android with Smack -How to get list of online users?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack

I am working with **jivesoftware Smack SDk** for real time chatting functionality.
For creating connection I am using following code ,

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);

    config.setServiceName("world-pc");
    config.setHost(serverAddress);
    config.setPort(5222);
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
    connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
    connection.connect();
    connection.login("username","password");
```

And its working amazingly fine.
Now the thing is that, I want to get online status of particular user or to get list of all users who are online.
I have tried many solutions from stack overflow, but nothing works for me.
One of my solution which I tried is,

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
connection.sendPacket(presence);
Roster roster = xmppConnection.getRoster();
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
Presence presence;

for(RosterEntry entry : entries) {
presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

System.out.println(entry.getUser());
System.out.println(presence.getType().name());
System.out.println(presence.getStatus());
 }
```

This returns me a list, but the status is null for all users.
Please some one help me with accurate solution.

Thank you

Comment: Do your client send Presence?

Comment: yes..Please check edited question

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Presence.Type.subscribe` in order to know (being a user), the status of another user:

```
Presence subscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
subscribe.setTo('another_user@example.com');
connection.sendPacket(subscribe);
```

And the "another_user" should approves your request in the same way:

```
Presence subscribe = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
subscribe.setTo('another_user@example.com');
connection.sendPacket(subscribe);
```

Comment: ok and is there any listener who listens for the users status change?

Comment: @Jay Vyas try RosterListener

Answer (score 2):

Presence it's made by a `TYPE` (like: `Presence.Type.available` or `Presence.Type.unavailable`) and a custom nullable `status` from User (like "Hello World!" or "Today I'm happy" or "At Work right now").

To set status, simply set it before send:

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
presence.setStatus("Online and ready to chat");
connection.sendStanza(presence); //or old one: connection.sendPacket(presence)
```

Comment: I dont want to set my status..
I want status of other users,
And I did'nt find any method like " sendStanza " for connection object

Comment: Each user can only set their own "Status", so basically if all set their own status you'll be able to get it as a String not null. Of course you MUST manage the possibility of null as getStatus (check it and set to ""). If you don't find any "connection.sendStanza()" method just use old one "sendPacket", you are using an old version of SMACK.

Comment: Ok let me try as par your suggestion

Comment: I'm read again your question, maybe there is a big misleading around: in Openfire (or any Server) "status" means "connected || disconnected || foo" to the server. Client side, "status" it's mapped and masked with Presence, a system that allow any User to mask itself to others (example: Skype's invisible), available (and online), do not disturb (and online) and so on.An user can be unavailable (for other User allowed to check avaiability by Roster) while online in server. More, Presence has a "status" that is just a message like Skype's Personal Message.Server-status it's not visible to clients

Comment: Status in sense,
I want to check if user is connected with the open fire server before sending him/her message

Comment: My answer solve the problem about "status in Roster is null", but about "status in sense" you have to start from @manolodewin answer